# How to add custom build steps to TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I found these custom build tasks for TFS at https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks . How do I make these tasks available to my TFS build server ? The documentation is not very clear.

Comment: They are the out-of-the-box tasks and should not need uploading. Your TFS/VSTS instance already includes them.

Comment: I don't have many of those tasks, i.e. CopyFile. Am I running an old version of Tfs build 2015? How can I tell?

Comment: You should update your TFS server at least to TFS 2015 Update 1, and I would recommend that you update to the latest supported version of TFS 2015 Update 2.

Answer (score 5):

Those aren't custom build tasks... those are the official build tasks that are included in VSTS/TFS.

The documentation on how to upload them is actually [extremely clear and well-documented](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli):

- Install the TFX CLI
- [Use the command `tfx build tasks upload` to upload the task.](https://github.com/Microsoft/tfs-cli/blob/master/docs/buildtasks.md)

If you're using on-premise TFS, some of the unpublished tasks may not work as they may depend on a later version of the build agent than what ships with TFS currently.